# seo 301 vs domain redirect

Tags: seo, domains, 301-redirect

I have a website with a navigation in different languages (language can be switched) and content that was submitted by users in almost any language. And I'll register many many domainendings for my businessname.

So, do I now redirect (by 301) all of them to the .com domain. **Or** do I redirect not by 301, instead pointing my countryspecific domains to the countryspecific version of the website, that serves the website in the langeuage of that country and point every other domain (not countryspecific) to the version with the english navigation.

First approach would built massive pagerank by backlinks, because 301d pass all pagerank to the redirected site (I got that info out of Matt Cutts videos). But I heared a .com domain has a pretty hard time to show up on top in lets say german search result of google.de, even tough it serves also german content.

Second approach: Every domain would not have so much pagerank, but I heared that Google takes countryspecific TLDs as a huge ranking boost, if you are searching eg. from google.de then most likely .de domains will show up higher in the search results.

I guess nobody can know what's better, because nobody know the algorithm of google, but anyway please give me your feedback.

Comment: Buying more domains does not add value ***at all!*** Your logic is way off. You are not going to build rank with 301 redirects and many domains. It just does not work that way. If it did, then everyone would do it.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I say the .com domain will have more pagerank  when everything 301s to it, then one single domain that uses server-side redirect (I hope this is the correct name of this redirect I'm not sure). Because people can only link to the .com domain... not to many many different domains

Comment: I may have misunderstood. We get people asking questions all the time about increasing rank or search visibility by adding domain names through one scheme or another. Ranking one site is always best. However, having unique sites with unique content is okay but not as a linking pyramid/mesh scheme or even redirecting to a single site. There is no short-cut to rank these days. Cheers!!

Comment: I serve the same content on every domain, only the navigations language is changing

Comment: You will get into duplicate content issues if the content is in the same language, if not the same language, then you should be fine.

Comment: I hope google serves the content of the right countrys TLD. I'm not sure if they choose one copy of the duplicates on each domain before the search  or if they coose one copy after each search. Will be nice to see, how they do it.

Comment: .com sites should show up in most google.xx sites, though maybe not all. If your content is duplicate, you will want to consider using the canonical tag back to the original. I think I get what you are trying to do, but I am not sure how to achieve it. I am not an expert in ranking languages and ccTLD sites. Sorry. It is not something I have ever had to get into so I have not paid attention. If I think of something intersting, I will chime in! Cheers!!

Comment: thx. I'm also thinking about ip based delivery. I will just test everything out. Anyway I have to buy many domains for brandprotection. I don't want other people to use the same name...

Comment: Ah ha! Yes. Brand protection is a consideration. Could be expensive... ;-) Cheers Mate!!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I personally would build out each country specific site.

A 301 redirect will only push value for so long before Google says it's no longer valuable. If you just redirect and those domains have value, they will eventually lose it so in my opinion, it would be better to build out each one.

Would be curious to know what you decide and why. :)